# Open a table using a value saved in SQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server

I'm building a calculator and it works in table, now I decided that I want to save it in the SQL, no problem until there.

My problem is because I want to show the saved table back and in fact the tables just open after I click in one of the icons, here's an example:

```
$('#table1').on('click', function(){
        $('#calc1').slideDown(1000);
});
```

As you can see the calc1 will open after I click on table1, what I want is a way to open calc1 and show the saved value without need to click it, the person will click on his saved table and the table will open with the rights values there.

I already can save the previous values in sql, also I know how to retrieve this value from there, just need the table open automatic.

Comment: Do you need to store it on the server at all? Could you not just store the data in a local cookie or in local storage? Sounds like quite a weird calculator you're building.

Comment: No, cuz the whole idea is that anyone, anywhere can open it, if I use a cookie only the owner on his own computer will be able to open see the saved files.

Comment: Like I said, this sounds like a really weird calculator...

Comment: maybe, but if the people can't open it anywhere the project won't make sents.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was already in my question:
I just need to check a variable that will have the value of sql server, if the value is X table X will open...